# Is there a way to test HTML element in angularjs? [Here is my app in plunkr][1] [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/4jttdczt/

Tags: html, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm new to angularjs trying to test HTML elements but my test gets failed.Actually,i want to test the HTML element's value or text which it contain.
can anyone suggest me how can i achieve it?
here is my controllerspec:

```
describe('myAppCtrl', function() {
    var scope, controller, httpBackend;


    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope;
        controller = $controller;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    }));


     it('should show the text of element',function() {
    expect($('#testtext')).toBe('First Angular JS App');
}); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing above is with Karma for unit testing, and is only loading up the modules you've specified. In this case it loads the module myApp, but myApp doesn't have any reference to HTML and doesn't load the DOM itself.

If you want to test HTML elements directly, take a look at end to end testing using Protractor:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing

Comment: what do you mean directly?i does not understand can you elaborate i am doing angular for the first time

Comment: You say you want to test an HTML elements value/text. The only way to do that is if the HTML is loaded; it looks like you're running Karma unit tests, which does not load up HTML. You want to run Protractor end to end tests, which loads HTML.

Comment: yup i am running unit test with karma and jasmine i have no idea of Protractor